# Extracting Parameters in ShiroFiler for MultiPart Forms

Tags: java, csrf, multipartform-data, shiro

I'm trying to implement a filter for CSRF protection using a Shiro filer and am having trouble getting the value of a form parameter from a "multipart/form-data" request.

Does anyone know a way to implement this, or perhaps even a better approach to handle CSRF generically using Shiro?